# Android - can an imageView float around on the screen?

Tags: android, view, imageview

I have a quick question. Im currently using bitmaps that get drawn above a dynamic moving object on screen and when a user clicks them Im using some custom code to open a view with a registered onclick. Instead of using the code we came up with I was wondering if its possible just to replace the bitmap with an imageView.

Will that work? or should I just stick it out and continue to build on the custom class Ive built. After looking at requirements it became apparent to me that an imageview would have all the built in functionality that I would need to do what I want. Or is there a better view class that would work for a dynamically moving view on the screen that moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [animations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) for moving views.

example:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(100);
set.addAnimation(animation);

animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
animation.setDuration(1500);
set.addAnimation(animation);

LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);

yourView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
controller.start();
```

Or in the custom view's onDraw, manipulate the [canvas](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2).

Comment: Im already using the canvas and drawing bitmaps on it according to the position of object but what I wanted to do was draw an imageview in place of the bitmap.  If I use animations wont the movement be predetermined? Or can I use them to just allow the views to move according to user input from the phones sensors. Thanks for the response by the way :)

Comment: You can always do the animations dinamically. But if you want to use the phones sensors, I think performance would be better if you used canvas, or even openGl or some 2d framework

Comment: Yeah I have used a canvas to draw the bitmaps on as the user moves the phone. I mean I could simply replace bitmaps everywhere with imageviews and just load the image strait to the image view and pass it around like that but I wasnt sure if you could draw a dynamically moving imageview like that on a canvas and before I rewrote my code I wanted a couple opinions on the matter.

Comment: @Tamas This will animating the layout for few secs only. how to animate the layout continuously.